# Design database of a file storage

Tags: javascript, database, relational-database, system

How should I structure my relational database for a file system so that I am able to achieve this property

i) I need to allow the creation of a new folder or upload of a new file at the root of the
storage or inside any subfolder.

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Do you have a schema for representing this 'file system'? In particular, if you have subfolders, do you have sub-subfolders, etc? Then how do you expect to represent the nesting? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I do have folders inside sub-folders and so on. I am stuck in how to represent it . I am thinking to use a NO-SQL database to represent each folder and it's childrens(files,folders) . I am not able to correctly solve this .